# randomWalk.java what am i missing (Beginner)

Tags: java

I have most of the code written im just having some difficulty finishing up.  I am supposed to create some code that will have a square randomly walk around on the drawing board until it walks off the screen.  I can get it to work a little bit but i have a feeling it's not correct.  Any help will be appreciate.

Here is an example of what it is supposed to look like
[image: RandomWalking]

Here is my code so far the problem im most concerned about is the walkingRandom method it has stars by it

```js
public class RandomWalk {

// DrawingPanel will have dimensions DIM by DIM
public static final int DIM = 400;

// Start the random walk in the center of the screen
public static final int CENTER = DIM / 2;

// how big should the cursor appear?
public static final int CURSOR_DIM = 10;

// how long should the cursor saty in one place?
public static final int SLEEP_TIME = 5; // milliseconds

public static void main( String[] args ) {
    DrawingPanel panel = new DrawingPanel( DIM, DIM );
    
    Random rand = new Random();
    
    walkRandomly( panel, rand );
}

/**
 * Draw a random walk on the panel.
 * Stop as soon as you walk off the panel.
 * Each random step should go only in one
 * of these directions: left, right, up, down.
 * @param panel a DrawingPanel to draw the
 *        random walk on
 * @param rand a Java Random object to be
 *        used to generate random steps
 */
public static void walkRandomly( DrawingPanel panel, Random rand ) {
    Graphics g = panel.getGraphics();
    
    // start in center of panel
    int x = CENTER;
    int y = CENTER;
    
    // Randomly step left, right, up, or down
    // until cursor goes off screen.
    while ( onScreen( x, y ) ) {
    
        // Draw the cursor in BLACK
        g.fillRect(x, y, CURSOR_DIM, CURSOR_DIM);
        // Wait a bit.
        panel.sleep( SLEEP_TIME );
        // Show a shadow version of the cursor
        g.setColor(Color.GRAY);
        g.fillRect(x, y, CURSOR_DIM, CURSOR_DIM);
        
        
        // Choose a new location for the cursor
        //*********************************
        if (rand.nextInt() < DIM - 300){
            x--;
        } else if (rand.nextInt() < DIM / 2){
            x++;
        } else if (rand.nextInt() < DIM - 100){
            y--;
        } else if (rand.nextInt() < DIM) {
            y++;
        }
        //*********************************
         
        
        // draw the cursor at its new location
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.fillRect(x, y, CURSOR_DIM, CURSOR_DIM);
    }
}

/**
 * determine whether (x, y) is a point on the panel.
 * @param x the x-coord of the cursor
 * @param y the y-coord of the cursor
 * @return true if (x,y) is on the screen,
 *         false if (x,y) is off the screen
 */
public static boolean onScreen( int x, int y ) {
    // x/y high = 400, x/y low = 0
    //*********************************
    return (x <= DIM && x >= 0 || y <= DIM && y >= 0);
  
}
}
```

Comment: Your 'choose a new positon' code is deciding to increment / decrement x and y based on whether a random int meets certain arbitrary criteria.   I think that will result in a very weird distribution of choices.   Isn't what you really want to *randomly* decide to increment / decrement each value with 50/50 chance of doing each?   Or maybe you want 1/3 chance of increment/do nothing/decrement?

Comment: On second thought, for a random walk, you probably want to pick a fixed length vector and chose a random angle, then calculate new x/y based on that.

Comment: Where do you think it is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a few issues with your code. You did not quite clarify in your question, but I assume that:

- All directions should have the same probability of occurring
- The cursor can only move "full steps" i.e. it has to move by `CURSOR_DIM` at a time, not less (that's what seems to be happening in your example)

The problem is mainly in the method `walkRandomly`, I suggest that you select the next direction as follows:

```
// Choose a new location for the cursor
    int direction = rand.nextInt(4);  //0=left, 1=right, 2=up, 3=down
    if (direction == 0){
        x -= CURSOR_DIM; //The step should be equal to the cursor width, not 1
    } else if (direction == 1){
        x += CURSOR_DIM;
    } else if (direction == 2){
        //you usually subtract to go up, the origin being the upper-left corner
        y -= CURSOR_DIM;
    } else if (direction == 3) {
        y += CURSOR_DIM;
    }
```

There's two other issues:

1. You are drawing the cursor in black at the beginning and at the end of the loop, this is redundant. You could remove one of them and have the same result.
2. In the `onScreen` method, `x` and `y` values equaling `DIM` should return false, since usually the bounds of an image/array are 0 to `DIM` *exclusive*. Also you should replace the `||` by an AND, because the cursor should be within the x AND y range, not OR.
   `return (x < DIM && x >= 0 && y < DIM && y >= 0);`

Hope it helps

Comment: thank you this is exactly what i was thinking.  I feel stupid for not thinking this through more... I had something like this before i didn't put the 4 in with the rand.nextInt()... and the bottom i thought it was an AND and not OR  thank you again...

Comment: Yup.  That's pretty much what I thought.  You should only roll the dice (call rand.nextInt()) once to choose the next state, and the distribution should be uniform (all directions are equally likely).
However, this example has only four states but there are really nine (or 8 if you want to exclude 'no movement').